# Javascript/Ajax Hijacking

Tags: appsec, ajax

I was wondering if below GET requests from a HTML file and a javascript file, are vulnerable to AJAX Hijacking/JavaScript Hijacking?

AJAX Hijacking: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx/
JavaScript Hijacking: http://www.net-security.org/dl/articles/JavaScript_Hijacking.pdf

1)

```
                    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    req.open("GET", queryUrl, false);
                    req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
                        if (this.readyState == 4) {
                            if (this.status == 200) {
                                //do something }
                                                  }
                                             }
                   req.send();
```

2)

```
                var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", encodeURI(ODataPath() + type + "Var1"+ Value1+"), true);
    req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 /* complete */) {
            req.onreadystatechange = null;
             // Do Something
    };
    req.send();
};
```

Comment: Please can you explain a bit more about the type of attack that you are trying to defend against?

Comment: More about this attack is given at http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx/

Comment: This is only a problem in [extremely old browsers - e.g. Firefox 3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29229283/413180). It's impossible to say from your client-side code - if it doesn't remove the "unparsable cruft" then it is likely vulnerable when a user is on Firefox 3.

Comment: Thanks! I think you're partially right. If I had access to server side code, I would have tried to find out if deny get is enabled which is one of the mitigation or something like while(1) or for(;;) is prepended with the response. That part I understand. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669690/why-does-google-prepend-while1-to-their-json-responses

Challenge here is I don't have access to server side code and from the client side code, it is clear that HTTP GET is supported. With aforesaid limitations, I wanted to get someone else's view on this, hence posted this question in the forum.

Comment: If it hasn't got the `while(1)` or `for(;;)` or similar at the start, then, yes, that is what I'm saying - it is vulnerable, as we can see the requests are GET requests. You're welcome to post to the site, however there's not enough information in your question to answer in this case.

Comment: I looked at the files again and it doesn't remove the "unparsable cruft". With the given limitations, can we conclude that this particular code is prone to AJAX Hijacking attack?

Comment: It seems so unless there's any global handler to remove the cruft.

Comment: Thanks @SilverlightFox. I wanted a discussion on this just to doubly check if my assumptions are correct. Thanks once again for all your comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only a problem in [extremely old browsers - e.g. Firefox 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29229283/413180). If your client-side code isn't removing any "unparsable cruft" then the server side is likely vulnerable. The other requirement for a vulnerability is that the JSON is retrievable via GET. From your question we can already see that these are GET requests, so you should either add an unparsable cruft or do some checking to make sure that they're on a modern browser.

The other option is to do nothing - this might not be a risk to you if such old browser usage is uncommon.

Answer (score 1):

Your calls are fine as long as they don't send JSON arrays with sensitive information as referred to in your sources. Perhaps you could use normal HTTPS requests for that info instead.